# Simulation pr2_controller_manager

Tags: ros, pr2, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying thia pr2s tutorial : Teleop PR2 arm in simulation (http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/Teleop%20PR2%20arm%20in%20simulation)

when i put the line: roslaunch jtteleop.launch
the error is :

```
 Failed to load r_cart
```

in the .launch is here
....

```
<node name="spawn_cart"
       pkg="pr2_controller_manager" type="spawner"
       args="r_cart" />
```

I suppose that the pr2_controller_manager was missing in my deps ... but i tried

`sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-mechanism`

http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_controller_manager
but the error always is the same

Tried change the type in the .launch and doesn't work

```
<rosparam ns="r_cart">

    type: robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianControll
    root_name: torso_lift_link
```

Next Error is

```
 Could not load controller 'r_cart' because controller type 'robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianControll' does not exist
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong ... i'm just keep few weeks Workin On Ros ..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47492/simulation-pr2_controller_manager/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a typo in the controller name. It should be `robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianController`, not  `robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianControll`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0